# Converting C# Regex To PowerShell

Tags: command-line, powershell, regex

Our Software department has a program that runs SQL scripts from a certain folder. I now need to replicate this functionality in PowerShell.

C#:

```
var commands = Regex.Split(sqlFileText, @"^\s*GO\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

I have tried the following in PowerShell:

```
$regex = [regex]'(?im)^\s*GO\s*$'
$commands = $regex.Split($sqlfiletext)
```

From what I understand of Regex, this should be splitting the SQL query into commands separated by the word GO but the output of `$commands` is a single string that seems to be exactly the same.

Example text:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
END
GO


USE [DB]
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table)
    [[[stuff]]]
GO

IF EXISTS
```

EDIT: Okay this is clearly something to do with the way I am creating `$regex` - if I create it with the following it works, however I don't get the case insensitive option:

```
$regex = new-object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex ('^\s*GO\s*$', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::MultiLine)
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the `-bor` (bitwise OR) operator? Of course you wouldn't get the `IgnoreCase` behavior unless you specify it.

Comment: I don't know much about `-bor` but I thought it was a numbers thing, not string splitting? And I can't find a way to include two RegEx options in the New-Object command. Please enlighten me as to either way of achieving this.

Comment: [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html) explains about the `[regex]'(?im)...` bit but it doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible ways to create 1:1 port of the C# constructor call:

```
$regex = new-object regex('^\s*GO\s*$', ([System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::MultiLine -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase))
```

`-bor` is the same as the `|` in C#. The extra parentheses are necessary to not confuse the overload resolution mechanism.

For better readability, you can also leverage the built-in call to `Enum.Parse`:

```
$regex = new-object regex('^\s*GO\s*$', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions] "MultiLine, IgnoreCase")
```

<s>I couldn't get inline options to work either, it appears they're not supported/broken in the .NET `Regex` constructor. They do work when using static methods like `Regex.Split`:</s>

```
[regex]::Split($text, "(?im)^\s*GO\s*$")
```

Upon further examination, the original command works for me. I made an error when trying it earlier. Here's a copy/paste-ready snippet:

```
([regex]'(?im)^\s*GO\s*$').Split(@"
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
END
GO


USE [DB]
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table)
    [[[stuff]]]
GO

IF EXISTS
"@)
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that's what you meant by using `-bor`, I've never found any documentation on using it like that. Thanks =)

Comment: What the... and my original attempt is now working... Feh, never mind. Appreciate the comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems creating a Regex object doesn't support multiple flags or something because I never got it working that way.

I managed to get it splitting with the following instead:

```
$regex = '(?-im)^\s*GO\s*$'
$commands = $file -split $regex
```